# HAXM install not working for Android SDK, no Hyper-V Installed

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, haxm

I've been trying to install HAXM for Android Studio. I read that Hyper-V can interrupt the virtualization of emulators and prevent hardware acceleration from working properly.

I checked Windows features for Hyper-V and didn't find it. It won't let me install due to my system not supporting it.

I'm running Windows 8.1 with an AMD A8-4500M processor on a brand new laptop. Do AMD processors run HAXM? Am I screwed?